# How to maintain matching orders between two python dictionaries when doing arithmetic operations

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two original declared dictionaries:

```
members = OrderedDict({
    "member1" : ["PCP2", "PCP3"],
    "member2" : ["PCP1", "PCP2"],
    "member3" : ["PCP3"],
    "member4" : ["PCP1"],
    "member5" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"],
    "member6" : ["PCP1", "PCP5"],
    "member7" : ["PCP2", "PCP3", "PCP4"],
    "member8" : ["PCP3", "PCP5"],
    "member9" : ["PCP1", "PCP4", "PCP5"],
    "member10" : ["PCP2", "PCP4"],
    "member11" : ["PCP2"],
    "member12" : ["PCP3"],
    "member13" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"]
    })
providers = OrderedDict({
    "PCP1" : 3,
    "PCP2" : 4,
    "PCP3" : 2,
    "PCP4" : 3,
    "PCP5" : 4,
})
```

the values of `providers` is the number of slots they have open to accept members.  So then I create a new dictionary of the total requested by `members` for each provider.

```
PCPcounts = {}
for m in members.values():
    for v in m:
        if v in PCPcounts:
            PCPcounts[v] += 1
        else:
            PCPcounts[v] = 1
PCPcounts
```

If I run my notebook cell just like this I get it output as the order I want:

```
{'PCP1': 4, 'PCP2': 5, 'PCP3': 5, 'PCP4': 5, 'PCP5': 5}
```

But if I use `print(PCPcounts)` I get:

```
{'PCP2': 5, 'PCP3': 5, 'PCP1': 4, 'PCP4': 5, 'PCP5': 5}
```

Ok, well I try doing an arithmetic different operation between the two:

```
differences = dict()
    for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(PCPcounts.items(), providers.items()):
        differences[k] = v - v2

print(differences)
{'PCP2': 2, 'PCP3': 1, 'PCP1': 2, 'PCP4': 2, 'PCP5': 1}
```

This is not correct. For example `PCP1: 2` should be, `PCP1: 1`.  Its taking the difference between the printed out order of `PCPcounts` and `providers`.  I have tried using `OrderedDict()` when declaring PCPcounts and this also returns them out of order.  How do I maintain the matching orders of keys?  I could not find this kind of question in another post. Thanks

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` instead of `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import Counter

members = {
    "member1" : ["PCP2", "PCP3"],
    "member2" : ["PCP1", "PCP2"],
    "member3" : ["PCP3"],
    "member4" : ["PCP1"],
    "member5" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"],
    "member6" : ["PCP1", "PCP5"],
    "member7" : ["PCP2", "PCP3", "PCP4"],
    "member8" : ["PCP3", "PCP5"],
    "member9" : ["PCP1", "PCP4", "PCP5"],
    "member10" : ["PCP2", "PCP4"],
    "member11" : ["PCP2"],
    "member12" : ["PCP3"],
    "member13" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"]}
providers = Counter({
    "PCP1" : 3,
    "PCP2" : 4,
    "PCP3" : 2,
    "PCP4" : 3,
    "PCP5" : 4,
})

PCPcounts = Counter()

for m in members.values():
    PCPcounts.update(m)

differences = PCPcounts - providers
```

---

Differences prints:

```
Counter({'PCP3': 3, 'PCP4': 2, 'PCP2': 1, 'PCP1': 1, 'PCP5': 1})
```

This can be further improved with the use of `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain
PCPcounts = Counter(chain(*members.values()))
```

Instead of the for loop.

Comment: Is this the most fool proof way to do it?  Is the "Counter" object essentially the same as a dictionary as far as indexing goes?

Comment: This is basically what Counter is used for therefore the least complex or more simply understood method imo.

Comment: If I try to do ```Counter['PCP2']``` it says its not subscriptable

Comment: Because `Counter` is a class you need to create a Counter then that will be subscriptable. Instead do `c = Counter(); c['PCP2']`

Answer (score 1):

What about instead of zipping using something like:

```
differences = dict()
for k in PCPcounts:
    differences[k] = PCPcounts[k] - providers[k]
```

I think the zip is making it overly complicated since you already have common keys